# Only static and const variables can be assign to a class?

Tags: c++, initialization, ctor-initializer

I am learning C++. Just curious, can only static and constant varibles be assigned a value from within the class declaration? Is this mainly why when you assign values to normal members, they have a special way doing it

```
void myClass::Init() : member1(0), member2(1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This looks like it is supposed to be a constructor; if it is, it should have no return type, and it needs to have the same name as the class, e.g.,

```
myClass::myClass()
    : member1(0), member2(1)
{

}
```

Only a constructor can have an initializer list; you can't delegate that type of initialization to an `Init` function.

Any nonstatic members can be initialized in the constructor initializer list.  All const and reference members must be initialized in the constructor initializer list.

All things being equal, [you should generally prefer to initialize all members in the constructor initializer list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6), rather than in the body of the constructor (sometimes it isn't possible or it's clumsy to use the initializer list, in which case, you shouldn't use it, obviously).

Comment: ok, that makes sense. But I've received errors previously stating that only static const members can be declared within a class. Does this mean that only static and constant members can be assigned a value from within the class declaration, in oppose to the intializer list or the constructor body.

Comment: Only static integral members can be initialized within the class declaration. Any non-integral members must be initialized externally from the class declaration. (i.e. you can't initialize a static float in the declaration, but you could an int, short, char or bool).

Answer (score 0):

Static class members don't belong to any particular object. A static member is shared between all objects of that class. Therefore, you don't initialize them in a constructor - that would re-initialize them far too often, for instance.

Now there is the question why only static *const* class members can be initialized in the class itself. The reason is that the class is most likely in a header, and that header is included in multiple translation units. This causes a problem for the compiler. In which translation unit (ie. in which object file) should it put the actual initialization? But for simple consts, it doesn't matter. `int const TWO = 2;` doesn't need an actual initialization in a translation unit, the compiler just remembers it.